# A function passed as an argument to another function

Tags: r

I create a function that receives another function as an argument. How to check if such a function really exists?

It is example:

```
f1 = function() print("f1")

f2 = function(f){
  f()
}

f2(f1)
```

How to check the argument f so that `f2(f3)` it doesn't cause an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to tell if it exists is to try it.  Wrap it in `try` or `tryCatch`.  For example,

```r
f2 = function(f){
result <- try(f(), silent = TRUE)
if (inherits(result, "try-error"))
  message("There's something wrong with ", deparse(substitute(f)))
else
  result
}
f2(R.home)
#> [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
f2(R.hmeo)
#> There's something wrong with R.hmeo
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: At first I thought the solution `exists(deparse(substitute(f)))` was better. However, upon reflection, the use of `try` and `tryCatch` is what I was looking for. Not only does it allow me to tell if I have a function in the parameter, but also I will be able to check immediately whether this function returns the expected type of result. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use `deparse` to do computations on code:  there are so many ways to compute the same thing, you'll never be able to handle all of them.  The main exception to this rule is to use it to set labels in plots or other displays, where you just want a string that matches what the user typed, you don't try to process it any further.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `exists` i.e. invoke the function only if it `exists` or else don't do anything

```
f2 <- function(f) {
      if(exists(deparse(substitute(f)))) {
         f()
    }
}
```

-testing

```
> f2(f1)
[1] "f1"
> f2(f3)
```

Comment: This does exactly what is asked, escapes the error, `> f3 <- function(f) {
 if(exists(deparse(substitute(e)))) {
f()
 }
 }

Comment: Well, plopping the `e` in there was a point about you'd have to keep in mind you were avoiding an error while things that end in `> f3(f1)
>` generally mean 'something positive happened' to new users. A little expansion on coupling `deparse(substitute(` to arrive at proper test condition for `exists(` would be valuable for all.

Comment: This solution won't work if the argument is the result of a function call, e.g. `f2(base::R.home)`.