# How do I initialize an empty data frame *with a Date column* in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

How do I initialize an empty data frame *with a Date column* in R?

I've tried a number of things, but they all generate an error message when I try to append a row with a date in the correct column. For example:

```
> test <- data.frame(date=as.Date(character()), var1 = as.numeric(), var2 = as.numeric())
> str(test)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date: 'Date' num(0) 
 $ var1: num 
 $ var2: num 
> test <- rbind(test, c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 123, 456))
Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Initializing the first column as an integer and then adding the "Date" class to it generates the same error:

```
> test <- data.frame(date=integer(0), var1=as.numeric(), var2=as.numeric())
> str(test)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date: int 
 $ var1: num 
 $ var2: num 
> class(test$date) <- "Date"
> str(test)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date: 'Date' int(0) 
 $ var1: num 
 $ var2: num 
> test <- rbind(test, c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 123, 456))
Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I've also searched for this error message, but the examples I have found all deal with converting a number into a date. I haven't been able to find any examples in my context.

What's the correct way to initialize the date column so that I can add formatted dates to it as above?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, it's sometimes worth breaking your code down to debug why it isn't working. `c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 123, 456)` alone doesn't work, before you even get to the `rbind` step. That's because R is trying to convert `123` and `456` to a `Date` class, but it doesn't know the origin point of where 'day 0' is.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is more likely due to concatenation as `vector` cannot have multiple `class`.  We can pass a `data.frame`

```
rbind(test, setNames(data.frame(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 123, 456), 
        names(test)))
```

-output

```
        date var1 var2
1 2020-01-01  123  456
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. The topic of this post was **initializing an empty data frame**. Your solution `nrow (rbind (test, setNames (data.frame (as.Date ("2020-01-01")), 123, 456)),  names (test))))` returns **`1`**, not zero, and is still marked as valid. My solution `nrow (tibble (date = as.Date (x = integer (0), origin = "2000-01-01")))` returns **`0`**. So what is an **empty data frame**?

Comment: @MarekFiołka the issue with the question is `rbind`  i.e. `c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 123, 456)` is creating the issue

Comment: Well, I must have read the title of the post too carefully.

Comment: @MarekFiołka Well, your own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877006/a-function-passed-as-an-argument-to-another-function) i read it literally

Comment: Dear @Akrun. Please see that this was my first question on Stack Overflow. I was a totally green newbie. I had no idea what it's the bronze, silver, and gold dots were next to the names. What these numbers mean and why some are hundreds of thousands and others are just a few. I didn't know how to ask someone for an answer. I don't understand why there's one on one answer and -1 next to the other. Hope that justifies me.

Comment: @MarekFiołka I understand you.  What I meant to say is that I also made the same mistakes that you made in the past i..e literally reading the question as it is.  In this question, what the OPs real objective (from the `rbind` code - assumption which could be wrong too) is that the person wanted to store some newly added rows in a template data created with 0 rows.  If we use `rbind` as in the OP's code, it will change the Date class to its integer mode.  Regarding your solution, I think also created a similar one `test <- data.frame(date=as.Date(character()),...`

Comment: @MarekFiołka If I use your template with OP's code, it returns error as well `rbind(df, c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 123, 456))
Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  date = as.Date(x = integer(0), origin = "2000-01-01")
)
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question about how to *add* to an empty data.frame.

Comment: Thanks. I stuck with akrun's solution as it is available in base, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: The title was: "How do I initialize an empty data frame *with a Date column* in R". My solution does exactly that, that is, it initializes an empty data frame with a Date type column.